# Profile python program that forks itself as a daemon

Tags: python, profiling, daemon, cprofile

Is it possible to run cprofile on a mult-threaded python program that forks itself into a daemon process? I know you can make it work on multi thread, but I haven't seen anything on profiling a daemon.

Comment: have you tried it? What happened?

Answer (score 0):

Well you can always profile it for a single process or single thread & optimize. After which make it multi-thread. Am I missing something here?